# How to add color space information in mp4 header using Media Foundation?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

Trying to add color space information (primary/transfer matrix/transform function) in MediaFoundation transcoding.

To set the color related attributes on

- `MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(..,..,pAttributes,..)`
- or the `IMFSample*` to `IMFSinkWriter::WriteSample()`

Only the Nvidia has color tag on output mp4 header, but AMD and Intel do not have.

How do I add the color tag for these two vendor?

Answer (score 1):

#### Intercept the buffer and insert the vui parameter with color tag into sps header.

1. Create a file sink wrapper, which internally create actual file sink by `MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink`.
2. Set the attribute `MF_MPEG4SINK_SPSPPS_PASSTHROUGH` with `TRUE` to the actual media sink.
3. Implement `IMFMediaSink` and `IMFStreamSink` to hook all APIs.
4. The `IMFStreamSink ::ProcessSample(__RPC__in_opt IMFSample *pSample)` will get the encoder output sample.
5. Create SinkWriter using `MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink()` with the wrapper.
6. When running, extract the raw buffer from `IMFSample*`/`IMFMediaBuffer*`/`BYTE*`. Follow the h264 or h265 spec to insert a sps header with

   - Colour Description Present, 1
   - Colour Primaries
   - Transfer Characteristics
   - Matrix Coefficients